# Button Enabled based on validation errors

Tags: c#, wpf

at the moment I have a text box with some validation code. In the program they can set the range acceptable by the input box. I'm wondering how would I disable a buttom if the validation failed for the input box. At the moment if my validation fails, a ErrorMessage Prompt appears saying it's out of the acceptable range.

```
 <telerik:RadMaskedCurrencyInput 
     x:Name="Pv" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
     IsClearButtonVisible="True" 
     SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
     Width="108"
     ErrorMessage="{Binding PvErrorMessage}"
     AutoFillNumberGroupSeparators="False"
     MaskedInput:MaskedInputExtensions.Minimum="0"         
     EmptyContent="Enter a Principal">
     <telerik:RadMaskedCurrencyInput.Value>
         <Binding Path="Pv" 
                  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"                                         
                  NotifyOnValidationError="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
             <Binding.ValidationRules>
                 <Framework:IntValidationRule   
                     ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"   
                     ProductId="{Framework:DataResourceBinding DataResource={StaticResource ProductId}}" 
                     Type="{Framework:DataResourceBinding DataResource={StaticResource Principal}}"
                     BringForward="{Framework:DataResourceBinding DataResource={StaticResource BringForward}}">
                 </Framework:IntValidationRule>
             </Binding.ValidationRules>
         </Binding>
     </telerik:RadMaskedCurrencyInput.Value>
 </telerik:RadMaskedCurrencyInput>
```

If the masked input box has an error, I would like to disable my Button

```
 <Button Content="Calculate"
         IsEnabled="{Binding CalculatorEnabled}">
```

Example:

```
Range $1-$10,000

I input $50,000
Calculator Enabled should be 'False'
```

How do I update CalculatorEnabled if there's been a validation fail or pass?

Comment: You already bind `CalculatorEnabled` to the `IsEnabled` attribute. So just change the value of that to update the button.

Comment: Hi @poke sorry updated post. Sorry if it was misleading but I'm having trouble updating CalculatorEnabled